# Docker on a Server 2016 Virtual Machine

Tags: windows, docker, virtual-machine

I've already tried running Docker on a Windows 10 Virtual Machine without any success.  I understand why, so I've given up trying to enable this.  However, it's got me thinking about Windows Server 2016.  As I understand it, Windows Server 2016 has docker included as a component/service, instead of an 'Add On' as it is in Windows 10.  Are there any reasons why a Microsoft Server 2016 Virtual Machine would not support docker?  This is more for convenience than anything else.  Dual-booting with windows 10 isn't a major issue and we've done that, but it does mean in certain circumstances I have to reboot to windows 8 for certain organisation-specific content that I can't access in Windows 10.

Comment: I know Docker is super trendy now, but we still expect questions here to be programming-related.

Comment: Understood, but this is specifically for development purposes.